# Import SharePoint site data into R

Tags: r

I came across a public data set, that I can't figure out how to get directly into R.  Typically, I use the following R code to pull data off the web:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://www.webaddress.com",temp)
data <- read.csv(unz(temp, "name_of_file"))
unlink(temp)
```

This SEC site, however has me a bit confused on how to get it directly into R.  One reason, is that when you right click on the link, instead of a web address, you get the following code:

```
javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cphMain$lnkSECReport", "", false, "", "Content/BulkFeed/CompilationDownload.aspx?FeedPK=37264&FeedType=IA_FIRM_SEC", false, true))
```

Here is the web address: http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/InvestmentAdviserData.aspx

Is there a way to get this data directly into R?  As of now, I download then open with 7-zip, save into excel, then import into R.

**Updated Code**

```
library(httr)
library(xml2)

res <- POST(url = "http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/BulkFeed/CompilationDownload.aspx?FeedPK=37264&FeedType=IA_FIRM_SEC", 
            httr::add_headers(Origin = "http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov"), 
            body = list(`__EVENTTARGET` = "ctl00$cphMain$lnkSECReport"), 
            encode = "form")

writeBin(content(res, as="raw"), "report.gz")
gzf <- gzfile("report.gz")
doc <- read_xml(gzf)
close(gzf)


xml_find_all(doc, ".//Firms/Firm/Info") %>% 
  xml_attr("LegalNm") %>% 
  head(10)
```

Comment: Did you try the link in that code?... http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/InvestmentAdviserData.aspx/Content/BulkFeed/CompilationDownload.aspx?FeedPK=37264&FeedType=IA_FIRM_SEC

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  Looking into RCurl now, which might offer a solution.  Will post if I can find it.

Comment: `a <- httr::GET(url)` followed by a `httr::content(a)` gets you a parsed xml document

Comment: Not sure if that actually works or is some sort of error page though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of those truly, horribly, wretched SharePoint sites that are popping up like crazy across almost every government e-initiative globally and making data more vs less opaque.

Having said that, I'm completely amazed this worked:

```
library(httr)
library(xml2)

res <- POST(url = "http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/BulkFeed/CompilationDownload.aspx?FeedPK=37264&FeedType=IA_FIRM_SEC", 
           httr::add_headers(Origin = "http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov"), 
           body = list(`__EVENTTARGET` = "ctl00$cphMain$lnkSECReport"), 
           encode = "form")
```

I used `curlconverter` to extract the web call after cancelling the direct download and viewing said web call in Developer Tools (which had to be up before the download started).

The "raw" computed `httr` request function looked like this:

```
httr::VERB(verb = "POST", url = "http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/BulkFeed/CompilationDownload.aspx?FeedPK=37264&FeedType=IA_FIRM_SEC", 
           httr::add_headers(Origin = "http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov", 
                             `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate", `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
                             `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` = "1", `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36", 
                             Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", 
                             `Cache-Control` = "max-age=0", Referer = "http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/InvestmentAdviserData.aspx", 
                             Connection = "keep-alive", DNT = "1"), httr::set_cookies(ASP.NET_SessionId = "vp5bt2nrl5m3l4tqq4mkbfrz"), 
           body = list(`__EVENTTARGET` = "ctl00$cphMain$lnkSECReport", 
                       `__EVENTARGUMENT` = "", `__VIEWSTATE` = "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... <truncated>
                       `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` = "C7F140E8", `__PREVIOUSPAGE` = "_n_AIWFFdFo0uFQroVexEbLyjk41mQczgUv0yM_5WfsMAs5Mr4_W9OsfhauW1md49E6AtLMLKvwsM3efjdsFxSQVs8m60rXjM2G3a38s-vs9jeifY7Z97KwNciQDnS3E0", 
                       `__EVENTVALIDATION` = "/wEdAAQgBK7oCoSH1SyM/nnv4+7OQ6BBh5UglL0V4PbvTmfHL5ETgQBTBoVSpnQmZd0nxKz/1ubqHHzGDP0ztOLUKJjXWi90IlgKV4uaEBSHcRvGBiO1/K20oSh88Xa2qq9BBCI="), 
                       encode = "form")
```

and, it's been my experience that these truly evil SharePoint sites need the various "view state" information, but I took a shot at whittling down and transforming the call and it's working (at least in the 2 minutes after I went to the site originally).

You're not out of the woods yet since:

```
res$headers$`content-type`
## "application/x-gzip; charset=utf-8"
```

even if you add:

```
`Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate"
```

to the `add_headers()` call.

So, since `memDecompress()` is an absolutely useless function, you need to:

```
writeBin(content(res, as="raw"), "report.gz")
```

To get the gzip'd content into a file.

Now, we can work with it directly:

```
gzf <- gzfile("report.gz")

doc <- read_xml(gzf)
## [1] "LAUNCH ANGELS MANAGEMENT COMPANY, LLC"       "JACOBSEN CAPITAL MANAGEMENT, LLC"           
## [3] "CORESTATES CAPITAL ADVISORS, LLC"            "MINNEAPOLIS PORTFOLIO MANAGEMENT GROUP, LLC"
## [5] "SHANNON RIVER FUND MANAGEMENT, LLC"          "AAC BENELUX HOLDING BV"                     
## [7] "WILLINK ASSET MANAGEMENT LLC"                "SPIVAK ASSET MANAGEMENT, LLC"               
## [9] "ANNALY MANAGEMENT COMPANY LLC"               "WOODMONT INVESTMENT COUNSEL, LLC"           
close(gzf)

xml_find_all(doc, ".//Firms/Firm/Info") %>% 
  xml_attr("LegalNm") %>% 
  head(10)
```

I haven't tried it, but I suspect you can take:

```
javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
  -----> "ctl00$cphMain$lnkStateReport", 
  "", 
  false, 
  "", 
  -----> "Content/BulkFeed/CompilationDownload.aspx?FeedPK=37265&FeedType=IA_FIRM_STATE", 
  false, 
  true))
```

the items identified by `----->` and put them in the obvious places in `url` and `body` area to get other content. Those parameters are from the "State Investment Adviser Report" button link source.

If you really don't want to write content to a file, you can try a non-exposed function in an alpha package of mine to inflate the gzip'd raw content directly in R:

```
devtools::install_git("https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/warc.gz")

raw_report <- warc:::gzuncompress(content(res, as="raw"), 50*1024*1024)
doc <- read_xml(raw_report)
...
```

Comment: WOW!  Thank you, @hrbrmstr.  I'm glad I'm not the only one that was frustrated with sites like this.  Your solution is brilliant and I have no idea how you figured this out.  :)  I pasted the code back up top.  But since this is new to me, how would I pull in the entire data frame?  Right now, I'm pulling LegalNm.  Thanks again, this is incredible.

Comment: The "how do I turn this ugly mess of an XML document the SEC created in a drunken stupor" is prbly better off as a totally separate SO question.